# Как ускорить цикл for?

Tags: python, numpy, for

получаю превышение ограничение времени, как можно ускорить цикл или использовать что то вроде numpy? суть задачи найти любое число и сложить вводному числу которое сделает вводное число палиндромным, длина обеих чисел должны быть одинаковыми
input:
3
2
99
4
1023
3
385
output:
32
8646
604
В первом примере из условия 99+32=131 — палиндром. Число 12 также будет являться ответом, так как 99+12=111.
Во втором примере из условия 1023+8646=9669.
В третьем примере из условия 385+604=989.

```
# Сумма значений b по всем наборам входных данных не превосходит 100000
    a = int(input())
    for i in range(a):
        b = int(input())  # (2 <= b <= 100000) — длина числа
        c = int(input())  # число
        e = "1"
        for i1 in range(b-1):
            e += "0"
        for i2 in range(int(e), int(e)*10-1):
            if str(c + i2) == str(c + i2)[::-1]:
                print(i2)
                break
```

Comment: Посмотрите takewhile из itertools для третьего цикла и map для второго. Если часа за 3 не найдете решения, доеду до компа набросаю

Comment: Исправь вопрос, чтобы он стал понятным. Приведи пример вводных данных и того, что должно получиться

Comment: @Namerek, Исламбек, вот только вопрос, не является ли это учебным заданием, которое не подразумевает использования `itertools`.

Comment: Тут надо алгоритм улучшать, а не цикл ускорять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для числа из `b` знаков попробуем в качестве палиндрома `b` девяток (`9....9`). Если разница слишком мала, попробуем `b + 1` единицу (`1...1`):

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    b = int(input())  # (2 <= b <= 100000) — длина числа
    c = int(input())  # число
    r = 10 ** b - 1
    e = r - c
    if e < 10 ** (b - 1):
        r = (10 ** (b + 1) - 1) // 9
        e = r - c
    assert 10 ** (b - 1) <= e < 10 ** b
    print(e)
```